# How to calculate the number of combinations of 3 integers less than n whose sum is greater than n * 2?

Tags: java, nested-loops

I am solving some java algorithm-analysis questions and this problem has me stumped. This particular problem asks for the value that is returned by x(10) where is x is the following function:

```
public static int x(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++)
            {
                System.out.println(i+","+j+","+k);
                if (i + j + k > 2 * n)
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Essentially, the problem is asking for the number of combinations of 3 integers less than n whose sum is greater than n * 2.

What is the fastest problem-solving technique for this problem, and just general "complicated" nested loop problems?

I set up a variable table and kept track of variables a, b, and c representing the 3 integers and a count variable which increments each time 'a+b+c > n*2' but after n=3, the tables became unnecessarily tedious. There must be a mathematical solution.

x(10) returns 220, but I do not know how the algorithm arrives at that answer and how to find, say, x(7).

Comment: 1. The question is about "3 integers less than n" but the code checks for less or equal to `i <= n`. which is correct ?  2. Are you asking is the code correct ? or is there a mathematical algorithm for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect.

1. First, the for loops should be corrected as

```
i < n,
j < n,
k < n,
```

because you mentioned "less than".

2. As you mentioned "Combination", but your code doesn't remove some repeated combinations, for example, if n = 5, there are only two combinations which satisfise the conditions, they are (4, 4, 4) and (4, 4, 3), thus the result is 2, 
   apparently your code will return a bigger number which is incorrect.
3. Could the result of this problem be a mathmatic expression ? think about this follow equation:

```
         n1 + n2 + n3 = 2 * n
```

this equation is a typical se called "Diophantine Equation", which is proved that 
there doesn't exist general algorithm to resolve all of them, and this equation is so relative to the origin problem, so i guess no.

4. I've changed your code, using hashset to remove all repeated combinations, hope is helpful.

   ```
   public static int getCombinationNumber(int num) {
       HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet();  // To save the unic form (or representation) for each combination

       int count = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
           for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
               for (int k = 0; k < num; k++) {

                   int[] nums = {i, j, k};
                   sort(nums);   // To ensure all the combinations of i, j, k form a unic array

                   String unicForm = Arrays.toString(nums);  // Convert array to string in order to compare and save

                   if (i + j + k > 2 * num && !hs.contains(unicForm)) {
                       count++;
                       hs.add(unicForm);
                       System.out.println(i + ", " + j + ", " + k);
                   }
               }

       return count;
   }
   ```